# Send mail with newline and Linux mail command via Pythons subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

I want to generate Accounts using usernames and random generated passwords.
However. I cannot send Mails with multiple line.
A minimal code showing my problem is:

```
import subprocess
import string

username = Test
randomPassword = abcabc
fromAddr='test@example.com'
toAddr='receive@example.com'
subject='Test Mail'
body='Your Username is ' + username + '\n'+'Your Password is' + randomPassword
cmd='echo '+body+' | mail -s '+subject+' -r '+fromAddr+' '+toAddr
send=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

The error is:

```
mail: cannot send message: process exited with a non-zero status
```

/var/log/mail.err shows the follwoing

```
[SERVERNAME] sSMTP[9002]: RCPT TO:<[SUBJECT]@[SERVERNAME]> (Domain does not exist: [SERVERNME])
```

A suggestion I found was to use

```
cmd='echo -e ' +body+ [...]
```

However this didn't solved the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you using a Python library for sending mail?

Comment: There is a set up mail server which we want to use, so we can just change settings in the the ssmtp config and everything runs without any issues. I would prefer using Linux mail command. However if that isn't possible with that method I could aswell use a python library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the body and subject in quotes. It's easier if you use an f-string

```
cmd  = f"echo '{body}' | mail -s '{subject}' -r '{fromAddr}' '{toAddr}'"
```

Note that you need to ensure that there are no quote characters in any of the parameters -- make sure you don't allow single quote in the password.

Comment: I cannot edit it. But after {toAddr} there is a ' missing.
So the correct command would be:

cmd  = f"echo '{body}' | mail -s '{subject}' -r '{fromAddr}' '{toAddr}'"

But this solution works like a charm. Thank you. Will mark as correct answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me

Comment: @ChrizZ You should look at triplee's answer, it's better than this.

Comment: You could fix the quoting issue with `shlex` but it gets complex enough that it might still introduce vulnerabilities; and there are other reasons to want to avoid `shell=True` too - see [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 2):

You really want to avoid the various quoting issues with Barmar's answer. If your Python is new enough, you want

```
send = subprocess.call(
    ['mail', '-s', subject, '-r', fromAddr, toAddr],
    input=body, text=True)
```

Prior to Python 3.7, you'll want to replace `text=True` with the older, more unclear alias `universal_newlines=True`. The `input` argument was probably introduced in Python 3.3. For idas for how to do something similar in older versions than that, and a more detailed discussion, see [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Comment: `mail` is a very thin wrapper around `sendmail` (though it has a fair bit of code unrelated to sending a message from the command line) so this is basically equivalent to prepending `f'From: {fromAddr}\nTo: {toAddr}\nSubject: {subject}\n\n'` to the `body` string and piping to `sendmail`.